# Fellow lab researcher adds me as (fake) author because his funds come from my fellowship

Tags: funding, plagiarism

I received a 3 year fellowship for a 3-year PhD in computer science at a well known lab in my topic. I am in my last year and things haven't gone well. I don't have any impressive research results, feel unmotivated and only have a single publication when my peers have 3-5. Of course I am to blame for that.

Recently, my supervisor added me as an author in a publication I contributed nothing to. I told him that this is unethical and asked him to remove my name. He then told me that it is not that big of a deal and that the rest of the paper was funded partly by my fellowship. Some months passed and again without being asked, I was added as a (fake) author in another publication.

What should I do? I believe that the other authors think getting my name on publications is something I need because, as I said, my publication history is very weak, but I would rather fail in getting the PhD than having it based on fake authorships. Also I believe that they are short on funding and need to put my name on their publications to use part of my funding.

Comment: Your fellowship provided money besides your salary?

Comment: Yes it provided money for my supervision and for "research needs" eg software,hardware etc.

Comment: Were you involved in purchasing/selecting that soft/hardware?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You are right that you should not be an author on a paper in which
   you did not contribute as an author.
2. It is important for anyone writing a paper to include all authors
   that should be authors, and not to name anyone as an author who does
   not agree to be an author; at your request, you should not be
   included as an author if you don't want to be.

However...

1. It is very unlikely that any harm will come to you for being listed on a paper as an author as a junior researcher, much more likely you will benefit. The exception would be if there is something else ethically or scientifically wrong with the work that does not allow you to stand by it (an extreme example would be fabricated results). I believe your colleague/supervisors actions here are intended to be in your interests, even if they are not in the ethics of the field.
2. The systemic problems with gift authorship are mostly about senior researchers bullying their way onto papers where they do not belong, gaining benefit for no academic contribution besides perhaps funding. There is not nearly as much concern about junior researchers being over-credited; if anything, the opposite seems to come up more often.
3. Consider that your colleagues may find your input and work in the lab valuable to them, and that while you feel your contributions do not amount to anything towards their papers, even insightful side discussions can be critical to the development of a paper. Consider also that they may consider parts of your group work as a collaborative effort whereas you are focused on your individual role: if your group approaches a problem with three possible solutions, and each of three people take on one of those solutions, the total work could be considered a joint effort regardless of which effort is successful first, and the unsuccessful paths may be considered not merely as failures but as constructive efforts towards narrowing the remaining possibilities.

You should not agree to authorship merely as a way of letting them capture your funding, but I would think deeply about whether any of your contributions in the lab could be thought of as part of authorship of these works, and if so, ask that you can be more closely involved in the drafting of those papers (even if it's just re-checking analyses that were done, or contributing references and background to the introduction or discussion) so you can feel more comfortable being included as an author.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add a secondary note to the [answer of Bryan Krause](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/183781/75368).

While you are correct that this very probably crosses proper ethical boundaries it is generally a mistake to get into a fight with your supervisor as they have too much control over your advancement.

You could complain to the journal, of course, but the backlash would come to you and also reflect badly on the other students. Just as a matter of personal survival, I suggest letting it go.

You registered your objections, which was correct and bit bold, if risky.

Answer (score 1):

Sit for a talk about your research and priorities with your advisor.

Be explicit about the "I would rather fail in getting the PhD" part, but also be careful with wording about fake authorships while doing so. Implications of unethical behavior are unlikely to be met well, and while you might choose to burn all the bridges, it is not necessarily what you desire, at the end of the day. Instead, a milder wording like "I really want my degree to be based on my own accomplishments and would rather not get it otherwise" might go better.

Consider their stake at the arrangement - they likely feel the need to successfully graduate you, and there is some external pressure. Possibly, to them "the student did not do much but I have pulled some strings here and there and they got to graduation nonetheless" is something to be almost proud of.

I do not agree with Bryan's implications of "gift authorship this way is not doing systemic harm so it is okay to accept it" - this is your own ethical stance, it might make your life "harder" but it is a very valid decision to follow that route nonetheless. The advice to view your contributions to the lab in a different light and not just focus on the funding is excellent, though.

So, talk to your advisor. Make decisions. Avoid drifting to the deadline passively observing it approaching. Figure out what is important to you and pursue it.